# Laravel in Docker giving 'php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not resolve'

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am having an issue with my Laravel in Docker.

Currently when I run `php artisan migrate` **inside** my container I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name does not 
resolve (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 
app_database and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

However, I am able to connect to the mysql using Sequel Pro and I am able to see the database created `app_database`

My docker_compose.yml is as below:

```
version: '3'


services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_nginx
    container_name: nginx_webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
      - php
      - database
    networks:
      - laravel

  database:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: docker_database
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_DATABASE=app_database"
      - "MYSQL_USER=app_db_user"
      - "MYSQL_PASSWORD=app_db_password"
      - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile_php
    container_name: my_app
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www
      - ./php/local.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - laravel
    depends_on:
      - database

networks:
  laravel:
    driver: bridge
```

The .env of my laravel app is

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=docker_database
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=app_database
DB_USERNAME=app_db_user
DB_PASSWORD=app_db_password
```

Can anybody share some insight?

I have tried everything online.

Comment: Error is very clear. The DNS is not resolving. You have `DB_HOST=docker_database` does the name "docker_database" resolve in DNS?

Comment: The DB_HOST is set to the container_name of the mysql service. 

How do I check if it resolve in dns?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to add network to database container

```
networks:
  - laravel
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar error. In my case the mistake was using `docker run` which spun up a new container which was in it's own isolated network instead of using `docker compose run` which will run the command on one of the containers spun up after `docker compose up` which will have access to the other containers in the network

Comment: saved my day, but I don't know why docker compose doesn't keep my container up and running

Comment: tty: true in the container configuration