SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failedss
I cant connect db to my laravel project
version: '3.1'
services:
    nginx:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/nginx.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        links:
            - php-fpm
    php-fpm:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: docker/php-fpm.docker
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        links:
            - mysql:mysql
    mysql:
        image : mysql:latest
        container_name: mysql
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        volumes:
            - ./storage/docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            - "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123"
            - "MYSQL_DATABASE=app"
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"

    redis:
        image: redis:7.2
        ports:
            - "63791:6379"




.env
DB_HOST=mysql
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=123


php-fpm docker
FROM php:8.2-fpm

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    default-mysql-client \
    libpq-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www

When i migrate
Output

SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mysql failed: Name or service not known (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as `name`, (data_length + index_length) as `size`, table_comment as `comment`, engine as `engine`, table_collation as `collation` from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'app' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)



I try anything and any solutions on stackoverflow,  I even tried to actually copy php.ini from the host and throw it into the container, it didn’t work either, at first there was a problem with pdo_mysql, then it was all solved and this problem appeared, I’ve been fiddling with it for a day and a half now ........................................................

In some cases I had to provide a UNIX SOCKET in my .env, maybe that helps?

I installed the socket, now I have this error
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (Connection: mysql, SQL: select table_name as name, (data_length + index_length) as size, table_comment as comment, engine as engine, table_collation as collation from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'app' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED') order by table_name)

You need to check if the mysql container is up and running and if it is accessible wherever you are running your php from. The error indicates that the host name is not found. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70215838/laravel-in-docker-giving-php-network-getaddresses-getaddrinfo-failed-name-doe

I would suggest adding depends_on:  - mysql

I got this error when trying to put invalid host like 127.0.1 using PDO connection, try to change .env variable into this DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
